# "callback on disconnected mediaplayer" when reusing MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My App allows the user to pick from multiple audio streams, and when a user clicks on one of the play buttons the following code is called:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    try
    {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mSelected.getUrl());
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, R.string.error_media, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and then the onPrepared listener:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
{
    mHandler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

This mostly works but sometimes when the user clicks one of the play buttons while the previous one is still preparing, I get error [MEDIA_ERROR_IO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_IO) error (1, -1004).  Looking through the debug log I see the message `callback on disconnected mediaplayer` meaning that it's probably trying to call onPrepared but the MediaPlayer has been reset already, I think.  OnError listener is what's being called:

```
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or somehow cancel the preparation of the previous audio?

Comment: `catch` block is called? Can you post the stacktrace too? Use Log.*

Comment: No the OnError listener is being called, I posted that code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after messing around with this for a few weeks I've found that there is no way you can use one `MediaPlayer` instance for multiple files because you can not cancel a `prepareAsync()` operation.  If you `reset()` or `release()` in order to play a 2nd audio file while the 1st one is preparing, then when the 1st prepare operation tries to callback, it will find that the `MediaPlayer` has been disconnected and give a `MEDIA_ERROR_IO` error.

So what I did was associate a different `MediaPlayer` instance with each of my play buttons.  I also tracked the state of each `MediaPlayer` instance (reset, preparing, or prepared).  Here's the code:

**MyActivity.java**

```
// Listener for every play button
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    for (AudioItem item : mAudioItems)
    {
        if (item.getPlayButton().equals(view))
        {
            mCurrentAudio = item;
        }
        else
        {
            resetAudio(item);
        }
    }

    if (mCurrentAudio.getStatus() == MediaStatus.STOPPED)
    {
        MediaPlayer player = mCurrentAudio.getMediaPlayer();
        try
        {
            player.setDataSource(mCurrentAudio.getUrl());
            mCurrentAudio.setStatus(MediaStatus.PREPARING);
            player.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            for (AudioItem item : mAudioItems)
            {
                resetAudio(item);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (mCurrentAudio.getStatus() == MediaStatus.PREPARED)
    {
        // toggle play/pause
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
{
    if (!mCurrentAudio.getMediaPlayer().equals(mp))
    {
        for (AudioItem item : mAudioItems)
        {
            if (item.getMediaPlayer().equals(mp))
            {
                item.setStatus(MediaStatus.PREPARED);
                resetAudio(item);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    mCurrentAudio.setStatus(MediaStatus.PREPARED);

    // play audio
}

public void resetAudio(AudioItem item)
{
    if (item.getStatus() != MediaStatus.PREPARING)
    {
        item.getMediaPlayer().reset();
        item.setStatus(MediaStatus.STOPPED);
    }
}
```

**AudioItem.java**

```
public class AudioItem
{
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private ImageButton mPlayButton;
    private String      mUrl;
    private int         mStatus;

    public AudioItem(MediaPlayer player, ImageButton button, String url)
    {
        mMediaPlayer = player;
        mPlayButton = button;
        mUrl = url;
        mStatus = MediaStatus.STOPPED;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Related to this but not the exact situation, I saw the same `V/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer` error zip by in my logs when I tried playing a video before `setSurface(.)` was ever called. I inadvertently never called it since I had it set only when my TextureView became available (`SurfaceTextureListener#onSurfaceTextureAvailable(.)`), which can only happen if the view’s visibility is `VISIBLE`! So the root fix for me was to ensure that `mTextureView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` was called at the right time.